# TypeError: can't round symbolic expression

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I wrote a function that computes the value of the derivative when passing arguments, but when passing a function with abs() the results are symbols instead of floats. However, the result I need to round to 2 decimal places and I can't figure out how to fix it

```
from sympy import * 
import numpy as np

global x, y, z, t 
x, y, z, t = symbols("x, y, z, t")    
def req1(f, g, a): 

    dfg = diff(f + g, x)

    res = round(dfg.subs(x, a), 2)

    return res
```

Comment: could you show us full working code , example and the error message you have so we can reproduce and help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`round` is a numeric Python function.  It doesn't understand about sympy objects.

To get a numeric approximation of a constant sympy expression, you can use `evalf()`:

```py
from sympy import sqrt, symbols

x = symbols('x')
f = sqrt(x)
f.subs(x, 2)  # sqrt(2)
f.subs(x, 2).evalf()  # 1.41421356237310
```

Once the result is numeric, you can use Python's (or numpy's) numeric functions:

```py
round(f.subs(x, 2).evalf(), 2)  # 1,41
```

Sympy also has a [`round()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.round) function, that first does a numeric approximation, and then rounds. (Sympy's round can't be called stand-alone, it needs to be called as `expression.round()`.

```py
f.subs(x, 2).round(2)  # 1.41
```

Comment: Did you try `x = symbols('x')`, `f = sqrt(x)` and `f.subs(x, 2).round(2)`?