# How to "ignore" a symbolic in a function and do the operation to the number multiplying it?

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import sympy as smp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import derivative
from sympy import Eq,solve
from itertools import groupby 

absulom= 2.844 #[mev]
sigma= 0.34 #[nm]

def potential(a):
    a1= np.array([3/2*a,3.**0.5/2.*a])
    a2= np.array([3/2*a,-3.**0.5/2.*a])
    nmax = 10
    coordsA =[ i * a1 + j* a2 for i in range(-nmax,nmax) for j in range(-nmax,nmax)]
    coordsB= [i * a1 + j* a2 + [a,0.] for i in range(-nmax,nmax) for j in range(-nmax,nmax)]
    distance1=[((- coordsA[k][0])**2+(-coordsA[k][1])**2)**0.5 for k in range(len(coordsA)-1)]
    distance1= [round(num, 5.) for num in distance1]
    distance2=[((- coordsB[s][0])**2+(-coordsB[s][1])**2)**0.5 for s in range(len(coordsB)-1)]
    distance2= [round(num, 5.) for num in distance2]
    distance=distance1+distance2
    distance.sort()
    distance.pop(0)
    grouped_neighbors=[list(j) for i, j in groupby(distance)]
    woutrep=[grouped_neighbors[v][0]for v in range(31)]
    U=0
    for t in range(30):
        V=2*absulom*((sigma/grouped_neighbors[t][0])**12-(sigma/grouped_neighbors[t][0])**6)*np.size(grouped_neighbors[t])
        U=U+V

a = smp.symbols('a', real=True)
f = potential(a)
```

since a is a symbol, my function won't round and sort the number, but I need it to do it, I want it to treat the number that multiply a (the symbol), not a itself? How can I do that?
It's giving me the following error massages:
" Cannot round symbolic expression ", " cannot determine truth value of Relational "

I don't know how to ask the code to ignore a while rounding or sorting. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can't round symbolic expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474622/typeerror-cant-round-symbolic-expression)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't really work